# Rspec test fails with decent_exposure gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've encountered problem using RSpec and decent_exposure gem in my Rails application.

My controller tests are failing, because of decent_exposure calls method "new" twice (Model.new(params[name]). Once with name (Brand.new(params["brands"]) returning Brand.new(nil)) and second what I expect (Brand.new(params["brand"])). I need somehow skip first call in my test file. Brand.should_receive(:new).with(...).once.and_return(band) is not working.

My test file:

```
let(:brand) {
  mock_model(Brand).as_null_object
}

before do
  Brand.stub(:new).and_return(brand)
end

describe "with valid parameters" do
  it "should create a new brand" do
    Brand.should_receive(:new).with(
      "name" => "LG",
    ).and_return(brand)

    post :create, :brand => {
      "name" => "LG",
    }
  end
end
```

So, can you please help me figure out how to get pass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Brand.should_receive(:new).once.with(any_args())
Brand.should_receive(:new).once.with("name" => "LG").and_return(brand)
```

I'd advise adding an expectation for whatever method the controller uses to persist `brand`. Usually this is `save`:

```
brand.should_receive(:save) { true }
```